# How to convert complex type to actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I am new to MVC, and trying to call a stored proc from the controller.

In the model I have edmx which has all stored procs as functions

> **Cannot implicitly convert type**
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVC.Models.xxcomplextype_result>`
>   to `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult`
>   *An explicit conversion exists.*

I created an object for the entity in the controller and in an action result function I called the function calling the stored proc and it returned the above error.
How should I convert the result set to actionresult?

**Code Sample**

```
public class DBController : Controller
{
    XXXXXXXEntities xXXXXXEntities = new XXXXXXXEntities();

    public IEnumerable<usp_xxxxx_Result> usp_xxxxx()
    {
        return XXXXXEntities.usp_xxxxx();
    }
}

public ActionResult ViewQuery() {
    DBController dBController = new DBController();

    return dBController.usp_xxxxx();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to return a class that inherits from ActionResult.

Probably you want something like:

```
public ActionResult ViewQuery() {
        DBController dBController = new DBController();
        return View(dBController.usp_xxxxx());
}
```

This returns the view with the result passed in as Model.

If you want to return JSON use:

```
public ActionResult ViewQuery() {
        DBController dBController = new DBController();
        return JSON(dBController.usp_xxxxx());
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm :D
btw is this the right way to call stored procs in mvc? Sorry i am new to it

Comment: In general that's ok. Although keep in mind that your UI is now super-bound to the structure of the stored procedure. So that if you change a property in your sp, your UI layer also has to change. A workaround is to return a "ViewModel", which is a class that is "specific" to the view, and not to the DB. You'll convert your stored procedure class to the "ViewQueryVM" class, and return that one.

Answer (score 1):

.ToArray() solves the issue.

```
public class DBController : Controller
{
    XXXXXXXEntities xXXXXXEntities = new XXXXXXXEntities();

    public IEnumerable<usp_xxxxx_Result> usp_xxxxx()
    {
        return XXXXXEntities.usp_xxxxx();
    }
}

public ActionResult ViewQuery() {
    DBController dBController = new DBController();

    return dBController.usp_xxxxx().ToArray();
}
```